# Find the longest consective run of given substring Python

Tags: python, arrays, string

Suppose given a string.

`str = "AGAGAGATAGATAGATATTAAGATAGAT"`

str = "AGAG**AGATAGATAGAT**ATTA**AGATAGAT**"

I have to find the longest consecutive run of 'AGAT'  which is three-time.
Find the count of each consecutive 'AGAT' and store them and then get the maximum of them in python.

Comment: Hey Shahzaib! Welcome to Stack Overflow. In general, this kind of question is considered low-quality (especially since it looks like homework). To improve it, you should share some code that you have attempted and point out specific parts that you find challenging.

Comment: This is my first question. So I didn't know about the trends. I would definitely try to post further questions according to guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're dealing with huge amounts of input data I'd go with a regex solution such as:

```py
import re

def longest_run(pattern, input):
    return max(re.findall('((?:' + re.escape(pattern) + ')*)', input), key=len)
```

This will output:

```
longest_run("AGAT", "AGAGAGATAGATAGATATTAAGATAGAT") # 'AGATAGATAGAT'
longest_run("AGAT", "AGAGAGAGAGAGAGAGAGAGAGAGAGAG") # ''
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> str = "AGAGAGATAGATAGATATTAAGATAGAT"
>>> matches = list(re.finditer("((?:AGAT)+)", str))
>>> m = max(matches, key=lambda m: m.end() - m.start())
>>> m.group(1)
'AGATAGATAGAT'
```

Answer (score 0):

```python
import re #Regex
import numpy as np
length = []
agat = []
str = "AGAGAGATAGATAGATATTAAGATAGAT"
pattern = re.compile(r'(AGAT)*')
matches = pattern.finditer(str)
for match in matches:
    length.append(len(match.group(0)))
    agat.append(match.group(0))

print(length)
print(agat)
answer = max(length)/4
```

The length array is how long a consecutive string of agat is - so there are 2 in the example, one of length 12 and one of length 8, if you divide by 4 which is the length of agat then you'll get the max consecutive agat string.

The agat array holds consecutive agat strings.